# Testing if the static types of 2 definitions are equal

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7, scala-2.11, type-level-computation

Let's say I come up with a combinator:

```
def optional[M[_]: Applicative, A, B](fn: Kleisli[M, A, B]) =
  Kleisli[M, Option[A], Option[B]] {
    case Some(t) => fn(t).map(_.some)
    case None => Applicative[M].point(none[B])
  }
```

This combinator maps any `Kleisli[M, A, B]` to `Kleisli[M, Option[A], Option[B]`.

However, after some time, I realize (admittedly with the help of estewei on #scalaz) this can be made to work with containers more general than just `Option`, namely anything for which there is a `Traverse` instance:

```
def traverseKleisli[M[_]: Applicative, F[_]: Traverse, A, B](k: Kleisli[M, A, B]) =
  Kleisli[M, F[A], F[B]](k.traverse)
```

so that `optional` can now be defined as:

```
def optional[M[_]: Applicative, A, B](fn: Kleisli[M, A, B]) =
  traverseKleisli[M, Option, A, B](fn)
```

However, I'd like to verify that at least the resulting type signature is equal to the original definition of `optional`, and whereas I could resort to hovering over both definitions in my IDE (Ensime in my case) and compare the response, I'd like a more solid way of determining that.

I tried:

```
implicitly[optional1.type =:= optional2.type]
```

but (obviously?) that fails due to both identifies being considered unstable by `scalac`.

Other than perhaps temporarily making both of the functions `object`s with an `apply` method, are there any easy ways to compare their static types without resorting to relying on hints from IDE presentation compilers?

*P.S. the name `optional` comes from the fact that I use that combinator as part of a [validation DSL](https://gist.github.com/eallik/eea6b21f8e5154e0c97e) to take a `Kleisli`-wrapped `Validation[String, T]` and turn it into a `Kleisli`-wrapped `Validation[String, Option[T]]` that verifies the validity of optional values if present.*

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that a method is not a value in scala, and values are monotyped. You can test that a particular "instance" of your method has the correct type (using a utility function from shapeless):

```
val optional1Fix = optional1[Future, Int, String] _
val optional2Fix = optional2[Future, Int, String] _
import shapeless.test._
sameTyped(optional1Fix)(optional2Fix)
```

but as with unit tests, this is somewhat unsatisfying as even if we test several instances we can't be sure it works for everything. (Note that `implicitly[optional1Fix.type =:= optional2Fix.type]` still doesn't work, I assume because the compiler never realizes when two path-dependent types are equal).

For a full solution we have to see the complete function as a value, so we would have to replace it with an `object` with an `apply` method  as you suggest (analogous to shapeless' `~>`). The only alternative I can think of is a macro, which would have to be applied to the object containing the methods, and know which methods you wanted to compare; writing a specific macro for this specific test seems a little excessive.